# How do I access the result inside json data concept?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Can anyone explain me how do i access the result of json data.
here is my json value which is i am getting inside ajax success by doing

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data.d)
    console.log("Success")
},
```

For above code what I'm getting is:

```
{
  "locations": {
    "location": [{
      "invid": "1634",
      "usrinvid": "1",
      "locname": "My Location",
      "businessunit": "My Business Unit",
      "organization": "My Organization",
      "desc": "This is the location created by the system for the new Business Owner. It can be renamed.",
      "netqtyavail": "0.000"
    }, {
      "invid": "1647",
      "usrinvid": "2",
      "locname": "My Second Location",
      "businessunit": "My Business Unit",
      "organization": "My Organization",
      "desc": null,
      "netqtyavail": "0.000"
    }, {
      "invid": "1698",
      "usrinvid": "20",
      "locname": "test dsf - Loc 1",
      "businessunit": "test dsf",
      "organization": "My Organization",
      "desc": "This location was added compulsorily for the new business unit -'test dsf'. You can update the name, description and other details of this location. You may also delete this location if you have added other location for 'test dsf'",
      "netqtyavail": "0.000"
    }]
  }
}
```

And after parsing those result inside success like:

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data.d))
    console.log("Success")
},
```

results are:

[image]

Comment: `how do i access the result of json data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `JSON.parse(data.d)`, in your case, is an object:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data.d);
```

You use that object's properties just like you do any other object's properties.

The object in your question is a bit odd: It has just one property, called `locations`, which is an object that also has just a single property, `location`, which is an *array* of locations. I say that's odd because 1. It seems like an unnecessary level of nesting, and 2. `location` is an odd name for an *array* of locations (plural).

However, if we want to access those locations, we can do so in the normal way:

```
console.log(obj.locations.location.length); // 3
```

Or you could list the names of those locations by looping through the array:

```
obj.locations.location.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry.locname);
});
```

Etc.

Comment: i am getting undefined in this case console.log(obj.locations.length);